# Strange issue with DVWP in sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, development, data-view-web-part

I have created a DVWP using sharepoint designer 2007, it renders fine. However, it throws "unable to display the webpart, troubleshoot with sharepoint designer" when I  check-out and save the page even without any modification. What could be the issue, how it be solved.

Note:
Am using XSL link for the template.

Comment: What data is being displayed? SharePoint list data? Web services data? SQL Data?

Comment: trying to display the sharepoint list data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this happens when the context is different between SharePoint Designer and the browser. By this I mean that the relative URLs aren't resolving the same. Try to get the XSL to work inline first, and then move it to the xsl:import.

Comment: actually, am using the complete path for the XSL,anyhow will with the inline XSL once again.

Comment: I found the issue and it is SharePoint removes the "../" from the relative path whenever the page edited through the SharePoint designer...so the fix is..Once you are done with the customization using SharePoint designer, you may need to change the XSL path link url through the browser...